# Get all component instances in the current application

Tags: angular, typescript

I am looking for a way to get all component instances currently displayed to the user (and if possible, get all service instances too).

I thought about using `ApplicationRef` but it only gives the appComponent reference.

I also tried the `Injector`, but you have to explicitly give the class to get the component instance.

Finally, I also tried with the `Router`, but with no success.

Is there a way to get all component instances in an Angular application ?

I should also state that my components are all routed and most of them are lazy loaded.

### EDIT : use case

I am trying to implement an event manager similar to Angular lifecycle hooks. This means I could write my component like this

```
export class MyComponent implements EventManager {
  onCustomEvent(event) {...}
}
```

Comment: What is the use case for that?

Comment: @AmitChigadani I'm implementing an event manager which works in a manner similar to lifecycle hooks. See my edit.

Comment: @trichetriche have you tried using ComponentRef?

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal coming from where ? I would indeed like component references, but `ComponentRef` isn't something you can inject in a service to get all of your component references ...

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
    import { ....ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
export class Test{
      constructor(
        private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
      ) {
        const factories = Array.from(this.resolver['_factories'].keys());
        console.log(factories);
      }
}
```

Comment: it is indeed working, but it doesn't return all components (some aren't even existing yet, but it returns them anyway). Is there a way to get either all components, or only created components ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Angular itself has something to help you with this problem, but you can solve it by creating a service named "SampleService" to store a ref to created components.

Here are more details:

In your component.ts

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit , OnDestroy{

    constructor(private readonly sampleService:SampleService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
         this.sampleService.addRef(this);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.sampleService.removeRef(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have around 100 components, if I want to store all of them, this means I have to write 100 times the same thing ... I have thought about this solution first, but the cost is too high (and one has to write this everytime he creates a new component, which isn't practical)

Comment: i am not much familiar with Decorators . but i think it can help u to avoid repeating codes many times

Comment: I am indeed looking around the decorator solution : I will decorate functions so that they get ran on event submission. But right now it's a dead end, like every other solution. That's why I'm asking for a solution there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I finally found a way of doing this : **decorators**.

Here is the decorator :

```
export function MsEvents(): ClassDecorator {

  const eventManager = AppModule.injector.get(EventManagerService);

  return function (instance) {
    eventManager.onCustomEvent().subscribe(arg => instance.prototype['onCustomEvent'](arg));
  };
}
```

With this decorator, I can call defined functions into my components (in this case `onCustomEvent`). All is needed is

- this decorator
- an interface that components will implement
- a static reference to the injector in the app module :

  ```
  export class AppModule {
    static injector: Injector;
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
      AppModule.injector = injector;
    }
  }
  ```